# Microsoft Graph Communications API 'Client Context' usage

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In some of the Microsoft Graph Communication APIs, we need to send the field 'Client context' like in the example below. I am not sure what the "Client Context" field is supposed to be.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-playprompt?view=graph-rest-1.0

Is it Just a random number that we can generate for each session?

In the same example, if we need to provide a local wav file for the playPrompt request, how do we do it?

I need help to understand this.

Comment: If anyone has made use of these APIs or know some public github project to refer these, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provide cloud communications API examples in their GitHub repository:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples

Look at the stateless projects for where client context is used extensively.

From my limited understanding, it's context that will be passed back from the API so your application doesn't have to keep track of its own call context.

Edit: To answer your question about prompts, simply provide a HTTPS URI to the WAV file. SimpleIvrBot in the samples provides an example of this as well as the correct format for the WAV file (256kbps / 16kHz / 16bits / 1 channel / PCM (Little / Signed).

Comment: Hi @ravi kishore, Please let us know if your issue has been resolved.